# Query fields after query multiple tables on multiple databases

Tags: sql

I am trying to do a interesting query. I have a lot of databases and they have a table with the same name (e.g : mytable). I want to find something in this table but searching all this table occurrence on the server.

I tried:

```
sp_msforeachdb 'Select * from Sysobjects where name=''mytable'''
```

This lists all the 'mytable' tables on the server.

I also used

```
select * from [table].[dbo].[mytable] where myclause
```

I tried to join these two queries, but I am was not able to find the correct way to do that (if there is a way).

I tried `case`, `join`, `inner join` but it is really hard to get what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sp_msforeachdb 'insert into MyMasterDB.dbo.ResultsTable select * from [?].dbo.[MyTable] where myclause'
```

OR (with db name in results)

```
DECLARE @SQL AS VARCHAR(MAX)
select @SQL = 'insert into MyMasterDB.dbo.ResultsTable select ? as DB_Name, col1, cast (col2 as varchar (50)), col3 from [?].dbo.[MyTable] where myclause'

sp_msforeachdb @SQL
```

To escape ' (single quote) use '' (two double quotes)

Comment: Its trying to get the results..but im getting an error
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '3E5' to data type int.

Comment: It means that in some tables one column is `INT` and in others its `VARCAHR`. List all columns needed explicitly and cast the columns in question to varchar.

Comment: Incorrect syntax near 'sp_msforeachdb' when i use the second code =/
its not declaring the values..but thanks..i will try a couple of things more

Comment: if i dont use 'where' it works..but list all the things i dont want to see..if i use 'where' it fails

Comment: i was able to do that using double quotes in the where clause i mean : where xxx = ''000''  ...then i didnt receive the error about varchar

Comment: Just one more thing anyone knows how to name the results by databases? im receiveing it..but i dont know which database the result belongs

Comment: To list db_name: `SELECT ? as DB_Name, col1`, to escape ' (single quote) in variable value repeat it as '' (two single quotes instead on one)

Comment: Something is wrong.. im getting a "Invalid column name 'my_db_name'".

Comment: You need to add this column manually to your destination table, one you are writing resuls to. You can update your question with the latest code you have: destination table and SP usage.

Comment: sp_msforeachdb 'insert into mydb_old.dbo.Results  select ? as db_name, col1, from [?].dbo.[table_contents] where cproduit="115"'

i was using the code to retrieve the results on the screen..actually i didnt need to use the varchar conversion and col1, 2 , 3 declaration:

sp_msforeachdb 'select * from [?].dbo.[table_contents] where cproduit="115"'

works well.,.i do not receive the varcharXInteger error anymore since im using double quotes. Now i just wanna name the results to see from which database im getting the results of
I dont really need to write in a results table on screen is just fine

Comment: When you `INSERT` you do it into a table. If you want to label by database, then you cannot inset data from `table_contents` in a table of exactly same structure: there will be column to store db name of the result. So you need `ALTER TABLE mydb_old.dbo.Results ADD DB_Name VARCHAR (50) NULL` and then `... select col1, col2, ...., ? as db_name from  ...`